# Django OAuth Toolkit and POSTMAN

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-oauth

I made a django OAuth server using Django OAuth Toolkit.

I've setup the code right and when I use CURL in the following way:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=geethpw&password=abcabcabc" -u"wHsGgpsHZyw8ghnWbEPZC8f4AZLgJIPmoo50oNWp:ZQcXeQWnae0gmX0SMi6Xn6puBnhiphR2M80UC6ugmffbrUd66awhbguYgxtQ1ufahJZehj4RlGjYu06fHkVgO15TURttSozj27nshl0AhFfCVzUKqTDubBimTSsK4yDS" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

I get a response:

```
{"access_token": "glzwHLQNvUNQSOU5kFAoopgJxiNHcW", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000, "refresh_token": "5k6jvCd2UxaRUGHKONC2SqDukitG5Y", "scope": "read write groups"}Geeths-MacBook-Pro:~ geethwijewickrama$ 
Geeths-MacBook-Pro:~ geethwijewickrama$
```

which is expected.

But When I try postman to do the samething, I always get:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

My headers are:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

If I remove this header I get:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

How can I test my APIs in postman?

Answer (score 2):

Your postman body should be something like:

```
grant_type: <grant_type>
client_id: <client_id>
client_secret: <client_secret>
username: <username>
password: <password>
```

Try Bulkedit with these, hope this helps (Hope you have registered the app to obtain client_id and client_secret)

Answer (score 1):

Get token from django-oauth-toolkit from JS:

```
async function getToken () {
    let res = await fetch("https://<your_domain>/o/token/", {
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: '<user_name>',
            password: '<user_pass>',
            client_id: '<client_app_id>',
            client_secret: '<client_pass>'
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        method: "POST"
    })
    return res.json();
}
console.log(await getToken());
```

Your client application **authorisation grant type** should be: "Resource owner password-based"
[image: oauth client application: Auth grant type]

P.S. I've failed to get token via **"Content-Type": "application/json"**, not sure why (django-oauth-toolkit documentation says nothing about that).